# Contentful fetch all tags with the GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, tags, contentful

Currently I'm trying to work with the Contentful GraphQL API, although I can't seem to find the option to fetch all tags at once. In the docs I find this article (https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/content-tags/tag-collection/get-all-tags/console/js) suggesting there is an option to do this.

Unfortunately this only seems to apply for the REST API and not for the GraphQL API? Or am I overlooking / misunderstanding something? When I use the GraphQL explore function, I also can't find an option to query the tags.. Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

This is from the future but If I get you correctly, you are trying to get all tags in a Contentful environment.

For Graphql, there is no option to get the tags directly unlike the rest API approach. If you insist on Graphql, you will be required to query a content type and then add the metadata to be returned with it. Your query should look like the following:

```
query {
  articleCollection(limit: 100) {
    items{
      title
      contentfulMetadata {
        tags {
            id
            name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check [docs](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#/introduction/previewing-content) for more info on this.

To get all tags with the rest API approach:

```
const contentful = require('contentful-management')

const client = contentful.createClient({
  accessToken: '<content_management_api_key>'
})

client.getSpace('<space_id>')
.then((space) => space.getEnvironment('<environment_id>'))
.then((env) => env.getTags())
.then((tags) => console.log(tags))
.catch(console.error)
```

Note: Only public tags will be retrieved.